# SQL - update query - update to next date value that is not NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a bunch of values that are currently on dates with NULL value (i.e. no data available on those particular dates).

How would I go about updating those values to the next date where there is data available?

I have a select query currently which highlights all values that lie on a date with NULL value (or false data defined by a value of less than 0):

```
select * from table1 a 
left join table2 b on a.id=b.id and a.date=b.date --joins dates table to main data set

where a.id in (select c.id from table3 c
left join table4 d on c.id=d.id where c.value = 000000) -- sub query identifying sub set of data I want to use as 'id' list

and a.date is not NULL and a.date > '1900-01-01' --a.date not NULL just identifies illegitimate date values that I don't want to see
and (b.value is NULL or b.value < 0) --identifies legitimate values that fall on dates where there are NULL values or false dates
```

So this query gives me all values from a chosen data set that fall on dates with false data or NULL values. There are a few more 'where' and 'and' variables I've used in the query but this hopefully gives a good base of understanding.

I would like to update all of these values to the next date in the future that is not NULL (i.e. has legit data).

Just a small example of what I'm thinking: **update table1 set date = (*assume there would be some sort of select sub query here to define next date value that is not NULL*).**

Just another note to take into consideration: the next date that the value is not NULL is dynamic - it could be 2 days from given date but it could be 2 years.

Comment: Posting some sample data, and the expected results, along with your attempt(s) to solve the problem will be really helpful. here.

Comment: You say you can't post your actual query, but you *can* post a dummy dataset with fake column names that match the data types of your source data as well as a simple version of the query you have, adjusted to use the dummy schema.  SO users are offering to help you free of charge and on their own time, so do please try to be as helpful as possible

Comment: In addition, it is unclear what you actually want to achieve here.  What does *How would I go about updating those values to the next date where there is data available.* actually mean?  Source data and desired output would really help in clarifying this.

Comment: You can modify your query to replace the confidential information with dummy variables. The question is a little hard to understand in its current state. Do you want to change dates based on info (your query says "update table1 set ex_date =") or copy over info from other dates?

Comment: Thanks for replying so soon guys, I'll add more context tomorrow - apologies, wrote this at the end of the day in a hurry - thank you for your help so far

Answer (score 2):

```
/*I would create a variable table @mytab in which I will put sample sample data
with dates and null*/
--Kamel Gazzah
--07/03/2019
declare @mytab as table(id int identity(1,1),mydate  date)

insert into @mytab values('01/01/2018')
insert into @mytab values(NULL)
insert into @mytab values('01/05/2018')
insert into @mytab values('01/07/2018')
insert into @mytab values('01/08/2018')
insert into @mytab values(NULL)
insert into @mytab values(NULL)
insert into @mytab values(NULL)
insert into @mytab values('01/08/2018')

select * from @mytab


--First Method with **OUTER APPLY**
update t1 set mydate=t2.mydate
--select t1.*,t2.mydate 
from @mytab t1
OUTER APPLY (select top 1 * from @mytab where mydate is not null and id > t1.id order by mydate) t2 
where t1.mydate is null



--SCOND METHOD WITH **LEFT OUTER JOIN**
update ta set mydate=tc.mydate
--select ta.id,tc.mydate 
from @mytab ta 
inner join(
select id1,min(id2) id2 from(
select t1.id id1,t2.id id2,t2.mydate from @mytab t1
left outer join @mytab t2 on t2.id > t1.id and t2.mydate is not null
where t1.mydate is null) v group by id1) tb on ta.id=id1
inner join @mytab tc on  tb.id2=tc.id

select * from @mytab
```

Comment: Will give this a go!

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it using apply

```
UPDATE T
SET Date = N.Date
FROM yourTable T
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 Date FROM YourTable 
    WHERE ........
    ORDER BY ..........
) N
WHERE T.Date IS NULL
```

Comment: Will give this a go too...didn't even realise outer apply was a thing...learn something new every day - only been doing SQL for a month but really enjoy it